# react native axios nested api call

Tags: reactjs, api, react-native, promise, axios

I'm making two API calls, one that takes in an address and gives me the lat and long coordinates. The second one takes should execute function n.1 setting state and using those coordinates and shows restaurants near me.

I attached `FetchRestaurants()` to a button, when I click it I notice the 1st function is executed but I have to double click to get the second part running, that is my main issue.

Any help is much appreciated. Thank you guys!

These are my 2 functions

```
  //api call - takes address and sets coordinates in state
  FetchCords = (address)  => {
    const apiKey = "kk";
    const urlPath = `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=${address}&key=${apiKey}`;
     axios.get(urlPath)
      .then(response => {
        const latitude = response.data.results[0].geometry.location.lat;
        const longitude = response.data.results[0].geometry.location.lng;
        this.setState({ latitude, longitude });
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }


  //gets an array of restaurants
  fetchRestaurants =() => {
   this.FetchCords(this.state.address);

    const apiKey = "yy";
    let coordinates = `${this.state.latitude},${this.state.longitude}`;
    const urlPath = `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=${coordinates}&radius=500&type=restaurant&key=${apiKey}`;

    axios.get(urlPath)
      .then(response => {
        const restaurants = response.data.results;
        this.setState({ restaurants });
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }
```

I also tried to run both calls concurrently as stated in axios docs like so. I still have to manually click 2 times to get the end result that is expected.

```
  //api call - takes address and sets coordinates in state
  FetchCords = (address)  => {
    const apiKey = "kk";
    const urlPath = `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=${address}&key=${apiKey}`;
     return axios.get(urlPath)

  }
  //gets an array of restaurants
  fetchRestaurants =() => {
    // this.FetchCords(this.state.address);

    const apiKey = "yy";
    let coordinates = `${this.state.latitude},${this.state.longitude}`;
    const urlPath = `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=${coordinates}&radius=500&type=restaurant&key=${apiKey}`;

    return axios.get(urlPath)

  }

  onClickFetch(){
    axios.all([this.FetchCords(this.state.address), this.fetchRestaurants()])
  .then(axios.spread((coordinateFetch, restaurantFetch) => {
    // Both requests are now complete
    // console.log(coordinateFetch.data.results[0])
          // .then(response => {
        const latitude = coordinateFetch.data.results[0].geometry.location.lat;
        const longitude = coordinateFetch.data.results[0].geometry.location.lng;
        this.setState({ latitude, longitude });
        const restaurants = restaurantFetch.data.results;
        this.setState({ restaurants });

      // .catch(error => {
      //   console.log(error);
      // });
  }));
  }
```

this is my render method

```
render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <View style={styles.v2}>
          <TextInput
            style={styles.txtPosition}
            onChangeText={address => this.setState({ address })}
          />
          <Button
            color={"red"}
            title="Search"
            onPress={this.onClickFetch}
          />
        </View>

        <View style={styles.v1}>
          {/* <Button color="black" title="Test" onPress={this.renderMarker} /> */}

          <MapView
            style={styles.mapStyle}
            initialRegion={{
              latitude: 60.200692,
              longitude: 24.934302,
              latitudeDelta: 0.0322,
              longitudeDelta: 0.0221
            }}
            customMapStyle={mapStyle}
          >
            {this.state.restaurants.map((marker, index) => (
              <MapView.Marker
                key={index}
                coordinate={{
                  latitude: marker.geometry.location.lat,
                  longitude: marker.geometry.location.lng
                }}
                title={marker.name}
                description={marker.vicinity}
              />
            ))}
          </MapView>
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Hello. You are asking us to debug your code. Please don't do that.

Answer (score 0):

Your second API call depends on the result from first API call, you have to wait for API response before initiating second API call. You can use `Promise` to achieve this.

```
FetchCords = (address) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    /* set url as per ur need */
    const url = ...
    asiox.get(url).then((response) => {
      resolve({
        lat: response.data.results[0].geometry.location.lat,
        long: response.data.results[0].geometry.location.lng
      });
    }).catch(err => reject(err));
  });
}

fetchRestaurants = () => {
  FetchCords(this.state.address).then((cord) => {
    axios.get(/*use the `cord.lat and cord.long` */)
    .then(response => {
      const restaurants = response.data.results;
      this.setState({ restaurants });
    }).catch(() => {
      /* do whatever u want*/
    });
  }).catch(() => {
    /* do whatever u want*/
  });
}
```

Hope this will help.